# Can't find variable: FileReader in Safari

Tags: safari, filereader, bittorrent

i uses html5 upload

```
    try{
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onerror = function(e) {
        };
        reader.onload = function(e) { 
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);
    }catch(e){

    }
```

but in safai when i upload a .torrent file ,it go to catch , and e is :

"message: "Can't find variable: FileReader"

Answer (score 1):

According to the browser status Safari should support FileReader:

http://caniuse.com/#search=filereader

Most likely the error is somewhere else in your code and the question is incomplete for you to get answer here. I suggest you more necessary details to your question, like a repeatable error example on jsfiddle.net, Safari version number and so on.

Comment: Safari 5.1 is the latest version of Safari available for Windows, and the web page you pasted said that the FileReader API is not supported in 5.1.

Comment: Good point, though I think there little reason for Windows users to use Safari and very few do.

Comment: I agree.  I was naively using it to try to reproduce some issues that some Mac Safari users were seeing . . . I hadn't realized that it's essentially been discontinued on Windows . . .